# Maven with OSGI and non OSGI projects

Tags: eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, osgi, tycho

So we have the following scenario

We have projects using maven with Intellij in a non osgi enviorenment and then we have projects using eclipse in an osgi environment. The eclipse projects are developing RCP-applications and is therefore using the plugin architecture (OSGI).

So we have:
Projects A – maven organized project in a non Osgi-enviroment
Projects B – maven tycho for creating application, but using eclipse project structure with target platform and so on.
Projects C – maven organized projects with maven-dependencies that should work in both projects A and B.

We also have installed Nexus with the p2-plugin so that maven-tycho can work.

The big problem we have is that we can’t figure out how to construct Projects C so that it works without problems for both projects A and B. In projects A we want that maven should work as usual and pulls down the dependencies as needed. But we also want that functionality in projects B (maybe with the combination Nexus+Tycho??).

How should we solve this problem. I haven’t found a good solution for how to do this. I have tried apache felix bundle plugin in maven, but can't get it to work as I want. Is that the right solution?

Comment: Do you mean that Project A and B depend on Project C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your best bet is to use the [Nexus P2 Repository Plugin](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Nexus/Nexus+OSGi+Experimental+Features+-+P2+Repository+Plugin).

You can develop and deploy standard OSGi bundles for the Project C using the `maven-bundle-plugin`, those bundles are directly usable by Project A via maven builds.

Then, by using the Nexus P2 Repository Plugin, you can also expose those OSGi bundles as a standard P2 repository, that can be consumed by Project B via tycho builds.

Comment: I got it to work finally, the working combination is Nexus with P2 and maven-felix-bundle plugin. A couple of things to remember is: - Eclipse does not work well with snapshopts. New versions are NOT handled in the target platform. You have to make a new deploy with a new version number every time. - maven-felix can embedd all the dependencies so that the bundle is working correctly.